# Prove/Disprove: $L_1, L_2 \in RE-R \implies L_1 \cup L_2 \notin R$

Tags: formal-languages

> Prove/Disprove: $L_1, L_2 \in RE-R \implies L_1 \cup L_2 \notin R$

My first intuition is "Yes", since we may look at $M_1, M_2$ which accepts $L_1, L_2$, respectively. Then, WLOG there's $w$ such that $M_1$ doesn't halt for, and so the machine $M$ which runs $M_1, M_2$ in parallel, **may not** halt.

Comment: If $w \in L_1$, then $M_1$ must always halt for $w$

Comment: I've corrected it. was sort of a typo..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Let $L$ be any language in $\mathsf{RE} - \mathsf{R}$, and consider
$$ L_1 = 0\Sigma^* \cup 1L, \quad L_2 = 1\Sigma^* \cup 0L. $$

Comment: But $L_1$ mustn't be decidable since it's in $RE-R$. Maybe I'm missing your intention.

Comment: No, I think I misinterpreted your $R$ to mean *regular* rather than *recursive*.

Comment: I'm looking at the intersection of $L_1, L_2$ but don't see why $L_1 \cap L_2 \in R$

Comment: What has intersection got to do anything with this? You asked about the *union* $L_1 \cup L_2$.

Comment: You can also give a similar example for intersection: $0L$ and $1L$.

Comment: I see what you did here Yuval. Thank you!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can you explain more about the intersection please?

Comment: It's best if you worked it out on your own.

Comment: I tried for 4 hours I still don't get it please

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165249/proof-or-disproove-l-1-l-2-in-re-setminus-r-such-that-l-1-cup-l-2-in