# Proof or disproove $L_1 , L_2 \in RE \setminus R $ such that $ L_1 \cup L_2 \in R $ and $ L_1 \cap L_2 \in R $

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

> Proove or Disproove
> $ \exists L_1 , L_2  \in RE \setminus R $
> such that $ L_1 \cup L_2 \in R  $ and $ L_1 \cap L_2 \in R  $

I tried to use the languages

[image]

the union is $ \sigma^* $ and the intersection is empty language
but I am really not sure if that really answer the question

Comment: Try to show that the complement of $L_1$ is r.e. by combining the other languages mentioned.

Comment: hi i am really new to this type of question

Comment: The second part of the definitions of $L_1$ and $L_2$ doesn't even make sense. Ignoring this, the neither $L_1 \cap L_2$ nor $L_1 \cup L_2$ are going to be decidable, and neither $L_1$ nor $L_2$ is going to be computably enumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both computably enumerable, and that $L_1 \cap L_2$ and $L_1 \cup L_2$ are decidable. I claim that $L_1$ is decidable, too.

Given some $w \in \Sigma^*$, I want to determine whether $w \in L_1?$. I proceed as follows:

1. First, I test whether $w \in L_1 \cup L_2$. If not, I can stop and answer **no**.
2. Second, I test whether $w \in L_1 \cap L_2$. If yes, I can stop and answer **yes**.
3. Otherwise, I know that $w$ belongs to exactly one of $L_1$ and $L_2$. I run the semi-decision procedures I have for these in parallel, until one of them stops (which has to happen). If I learn that $w \in L_1$, I answer **yes**. If I learn that $w \in L_2$, I answer **no**.

Comment: hi @Arno i am sorry i fixed my question

Comment: @mayacohen The answer is still fine as it shows that the claim is wrong.

Comment: i dont understand the answer but I can accept it, if there is a possibility to make it so that I can understand it I would really appreciate it

Comment: Man I don't understand how did you disproof the statement with what you wrote can you pleasake it more clear what was the contradiction

Comment: @mayacohen If you are completely lost when reading my answer, you aren't ready for this kind of question yet, and you should go back to the basics. If there is one concrete step you don't follow, be specific.

Comment: I don't understand why your disproof is like this, why we don't take the sentence and invert it to $ \forall L1 ,L2   $  to proof that the intersection and the union of them not in R

Comment: i dont understand why you dont do $ \forall L1,L2 \rightarrow L1 \cup L2 \notin R  , and , L1 \cap L2 \notin R $

Comment: @mayacohen Because that's not the negation of the claim.

Comment: then what is it? can you simplify this answer for for me, please, that's makes me really confused, @Arno

Comment: I dont understand where the disproof is please

Comment: why you didnt say that it contradicts that L1 in RE because we just made a decidable machine from that

Comment: this is the contradiction